# Making the column header the file name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new to VBA so this is some code that I found online and combined. Right now there are 3 parts (the last part isn't that important to my question). The first part "compile" loops through all the files in a folder and calls the second part "copydata" which copies data under columns with the header "direction" or "instruction" and pastes it into a new sheet "Summary". Right now the code pastes the data into the next empty column. How can I update my code such that every time data is put into a new column, the headers "direction" or "instruction" are replaced with the datas corresponding file name

```
Sub Compile()
Dim xsource As Workbook
Dim NewWS As Worksheet
Dim original As Worksheet
Dim FileNeeded As String
Dim xPath As String

'clear contents from previous sheet
Sheets("summary").Cells.ClearContents
' Initialize some variables and get the folder path that has the files
Set NewWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary")
xPath = GetPath
' Make sure a folder was picked.
If Not xPath = vbNullString Then

' Get all the files from the folder
FileNeeded = Dir$(xPath & "*.xlsm", vbNormal)
Do While Not FileNeeded = vbNullString

' Open the file and get the source sheet
    Set xsource = Workbooks.Open(xPath & FileNeeded)
    Set original = xsource.Sheets("sum")

    Call CopyData(original, NewWS)

    'Close the workbook and move to the next file.
    xsource.Close False
    FileNeeded = Dir$()

    Loop
End If
End Sub

Sub CopyData(original As Worksheet, NewWS As Worksheet)
Dim title As Range
Dim LastCol As Long

With original.Rows(1)
Set title = .Find("direction")
If title Is Nothing Then Set title = .Find("instruction")
End With

'Get last used column, and add 1 (for next one)
LastCol = NewWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

If Not title Is Nothing Then
    title.EntireColumn.Copy
    NewWS.Cells(1, LastCol).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    NewWS.Columns(LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
  Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If
End Sub

Function GetPath() As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .ButtonName = "Select a folder"
    .title = "Folder Picker"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then GetPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Pass the file name to CopyData function (so you will have `Sub CopyData(original As Worksheet, NewWS As Worksheet, TheFileName as String)`), and after pasting the data add the corresponding name with `NewWS.Cells(1, LastCol)=TheFileName`.

Comment: I need the code to pull data from files within a folder the user chooses (shown in the last function GetPath) so how can I make sure the column header is the name of the file the data is taken from?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
Set xsource = Workbooks.Open(xPath & FileNeeded)
Set original = xsource.Sheets("sum")
FileName= xsource.Name 'add this line

Call CopyData(original, NewWS, FileName) 'add the file name into the parameters of your sub
```

And then in your sub

```
 Sub CopyData(original As Worksheet, NewWS As Worksheet, TheFileName as String)
```

And then

```
(...)
NewWS.Columns(LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'this is your code, just to indicate where to add the next line
NewWS.Cells(1, LastCol)=TheFileName 'add this line
```

Comment: I get a ByRef mismatch error for the Call CopyData(original, NewWS, FileName) line

Comment: add `Dim FileName as String` in the sub Compile

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestions but the first row in the column becomes blank and it only pastes data into column b so all the data gets overwritten

Comment: I tried the, and its working for me... And my suggestions should not make the code write the data always in column b. Something else was changed.

Comment: Replace `NewWS.Columns(LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo` with `NewWS.Columns(LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=LastCol, Header:=xlYes`. I did not test that since my version of excel (a prehistoric 2003) do not support RemoveDuplicates functionality...