# Copy and Pasting only cells with values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can i update my code so that I only copy cells with data. It searches and selects the columns with headers "instruction" or "direction". Since it selects the entire column, I get a mismatch size error. I want it to only copy non-empty cells in the original worksheet and paste it below the next empty cell in column b of the new worksheet. This is what I have but I haven't tested it yet and I know the syntax is probably incorrect somewhere

```
Sub CopyData(ORIGINAL As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet)
Dim Title As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim dest As Range

With ORIGINAL.Rows(1)
Set Title = .Find("Instruction")
If Title Is Nothing Then Set Title = .Find("Direction")
End With

'Get last used row, and add 1 (for next one)
LastRow = newWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Not Title Is Nothing Then
    Title.EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set Title = Title.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(2)
    Set dest = newWS.Cells(LastRow, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
    Title.copy dest
    newWS.Columns.AutoFit
Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be able to help you.  Say we have:

[image]

and our goal is to:

- find the `Instruction` column
- copy only the cells containing data in that column
- paste into column **F** below any existing data in that column

The code:

```
Sub Soso()
    Dim rToCopy As Range, rDest As Range

    Set rToCopy = Rows("1:1").Cells.Find(What:="Instruction")
    Set rToCopy = rToCopy.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(2)

    Set rDest = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rToCopy.Copy rDest
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- no empty cells have been copied.
- my code is designed for constants, not formulas

If you have formulas in the `Instruction` column, use `SpecialCells(-4123)`

Comment: I tried modifying my code with your suggestions. I updated my question with the new code so you can see but when I run, it just overwrites the previous data. I have two other subs I didn't include because I don't think they're relevant but they loop through a folder of files and finds and selects the columns with the headers "direction" or "instruction" then pastes that data into a new column in a new worksheet.

Comment: @Soso  I will examine your new code in a little while.

Comment: I think your full code (see a previous version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50742738/1726522)) might help people to understand what you really want.

Comment: @Soso  Good news!  I ran your code.........the only change I had to make was from ***Offset(0,1)*** to ***Offset(1,0)*** .................my code only works on **constants** not **formulas**